# Understanding Clang's optimization when pointer is zero

Tags: c, assembly, clang, x86-64

**In short:** try switching `foos` pointer from 0 to 1 here:
[godbolt - compiler explorer link](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVAB9LclIj2yAnjqVMtdAGFUrAK4BbWiABMAZlKn0AGTy1MAOTsARpjEXABspAAOqEKERrSWNvZOrlExhnRePv62QSGc4XqYBnEMBMzEBAl2Di66mPrptKXlBJl%2BgcFhumUVVUm1Qj2t3u05nfkAlLqo1sTIHFIApC7eyDZYANSLzuaD%2BPQAdAjb2IsyAIJn5wQAnhGYWFQb1t4EABwaBBvf39Zv2wAhK63e6PZ6vZyOT4/Z6QwFXYF3B6YJ6DYjWAxbADsQIuMOskI24nheJ%2BBMcGxuJMuWIAIgAxVCoalXckbNDWehbZy0jYAVhkMhZF1eG1szG8EAmCJxCNJvzeGwAVDRotzeRA/sqJkLnLjLvLYRT6phbKYCBoYgAvTDqjb/PVXfGE1BUKgiL7bXm6/UwmjETWEvBen3BnYc%2BiA4OOIEx6WGxayw3OilKiJ2wOpibUJlCLYxjYms30S14G1KvDSx3Jn5pu1h30/RO0uXnGEbYiYAizWgbH0ylsXKRTVjSPnyByyeSoaTmDZCGZzW3LZyceQEaRyCZTADWIGczgOB%2BPJ9P4VHUm4E830%2Bk8iEIBkpA3U6mcFgSDQtgieHYZAoEBfj%2Bf4oGsajAJwjgyJwfC/gQwQPhAAQ3qQATeOUNzSGupBfsWBAAPK0KwmFTqQWDiuo7AofgnbFAAbpgD6kZg4hFNY8Eoa89QoaweABMQGGWFgKEEMQeC2Fhw58HQjAsFRPDSYIIgSChSgwao6ggFoGg6LxAQPpAUyoBEjRMQAtPhzj3iaxTGBA7h9A4MHuG02S5MoqSxHQjkedEXm0K5HR5HUDQlEMPkwYUtlNEMgVjMFgwtBF3QtHF7mcFMC6zPMXAjmO16kTOUjiG8oRmaE3DshpwAbJBBwyAcnAbBAuCECQ%2BarqQGyWN%2Bv7BB1GXdeuN7bqQe4Hkep5TQe57SFepCTnIpBFfej7PiNpDvogIAzAQETseQlBAX1wUPG1wX8LJbAcApl3CGIkikQA7gJESSXlUjjgtKFFfh7H7V8rpEqV5WVWB6i1Y49WNc1PXAf1K4ZcNr67vuh7TdNKhzQVS0rboa0vluH2ODjt5SMjROkAxxAxMY3BAA) - what is happening?

---

I was surprised at how many instruction came out of clang when I compiled the following C code. - And I noticed that it only happens when the pointer `foos` is zero. (x86-64 clang 12.0.1 with -O2 or -O3).

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t     u8;
typedef uint32_t    u32;


typedef struct {
    u32 x;
    u32 y;
}Foo;

u32 count = 500;

int main()
{
     u8 *foos = (u8 *)0;

    u32 element_size = 8;
    u32 offset = 0;
    for(u32 i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        u32 *p = (u32 *)(foos + element_size*i);
        *p = i;
    }

     return 0;
}
```

This is the output when the pointer is zero.

```
main:                                   # @main
        mov     r8d, dword ptr [rip + count]
        test    r8, r8
        je      .LBB0_6
        lea     rcx, [r8 - 1]
        mov     eax, r8d
        and     eax, 3
        cmp     rcx, 3
        jae     .LBB0_7
        xor     ecx, ecx
        jmp     .LBB0_3
.LBB0_7:
        and     r8d, -4
        mov     esi, 16
        xor     ecx, ecx
.LBB0_8:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        lea     edi, [rsi - 16]
        and     edi, -32
        mov     dword ptr [rdi], ecx
        lea     edi, [rsi - 8]
        and     edi, -24
        lea     edx, [rcx + 1]
        mov     dword ptr [rdi], edx
        mov     edx, esi
        and     edx, -16
        lea     edi, [rcx + 2]
        mov     dword ptr [rdx], edi
        lea     edx, [rsi + 8]
        and     edx, -8
        lea     edi, [rcx + 3]
        mov     dword ptr [rdx], edi
        add     rcx, 4
        add     rsi, 32
        cmp     r8, rcx
        jne     .LBB0_8
.LBB0_3:
        test    rax, rax
        je      .LBB0_6
        lea     rdx, [8*rcx]
.LBB0_5:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        mov     esi, edx
        and     esi, -8
        mov     dword ptr [rsi], ecx
        add     rdx, 8
        add     ecx, 1
        add     rax, -1
        jne     .LBB0_5
.LBB0_6:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
count:
        .long   500                             # 0x1f4
```

Can you please help me understand what is happening here? I don't know assembly very well. The AND with 3 suggest to me that there's some alignment branching. The top part of LBB0_8 looks very strange to me...

Comment: Dereferencing a NULL pointer (such as `(u8 *)0 + 0 * element_size`) is undefined behaviour, so it's not shocking that something weird happens, although it is interesting that exactly this happens.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't have been surprised if it just replaced the whole thing with `ud2` or `call abort` or the like, but generating *more* code is peculiar.  One might have to look at the output of intermediate passes.  A wild guess is that the compiler thinks this looks like the naive implementation of `offsetof` using `&(((struct foo *)0)->member)`, which maybe they want to support despite being UB.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Or maybe being UB, it made some parts of the optimizer just give up, leaving later parts to do something naive.

Comment: You also get the longer unrolled code if you set `foos` to point to an actual array of `struct Foo`: https://godbolt.org/z/sdq3b559K.  Maybe the difference has to do with whether the compiler can be convinced about the alignment of `foos`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is loop unrolling.

The code first checks if `count` is greater than 3, and if so, branches to `LBB0_7`, which sets up loop variables and drops into the loop at `LBB0_8`. This loop does 4 steps per iteration, as long as there are still 4 or more to do. Afterwards it falls through to the "slow path" at `LBB0_3`/`LBB0_5` that just does one step per iteration.
That slow path is also very similar to what you get when you compile the code with a non-zero value for that pointer.

As for *why* this happens, I don't know. Initially I was thinking that the compiler proves that a NULL deref will happen inside the loop and optimises on that, but usually that's akin to replacing the loop contents with `__builtin_unreachable();`, which causes it to throw out the loop entirely. Still can't rule it out, but I've seen the compiler throw out a lot of code many times, so it seems at least unlikely that UB causes this.
Then I was thinking maybe the fact that `0` requires no additional calculation, but all it'd have to change was `mov esi, 16` to `mov esi, 17`, so it'd have the same amount of instructions.
What's also interesting is that on x86_64, it generates a loop with 4 steps per iteration, whereas on arm64 it generates one with 2 steps per iteration.

Comment: Unroll factors are a tuning thing; the `-mtune=generic` default for x86-64 is different from the default for ARM64, perhaps because x86-64 CPUs tend to have larger caches or wider pipelines?  Or narrower pipelines so ARM64 can eat up the loop overhead more, if x86-64 is normally closer to a front-end bottleneck?  It could also change within x86-64 based on `-march=bdver2` vs. `-march=znver2` vs. `-march=silvermont` or whatever.

Comment: @PeterCordes you're right! `silvermont` causes 2-step iterations while the other two you named cause no loop unrolling at all.